# AJAX request not displaying information

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to check the entered username and email with the database to check its availability.

It checks the email perfectly fine. I am using the same code for the email but with different id tags:

Here is my form for username:

```
<label for="username">Desired Username</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="desusername" name="desusername" placeholder="Enter username" onkeyup="checkname();" required>
<span id="name_status"></span>
```

Here is the function to check it:

```
function checkname()
  {
   var username=document.getElementById("desusername").value;

   if(username) {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '../members/authentication/checkusername.php',
    data: {
       username:username,
    },
    success: function (response) {
     $( '#name_status' ).html(response);
     if(response=="OK") {
      return true;  
     }else {
      return false; 
     }
    }
    });
   }
   else {
    $( '#name_status' ).html("");
    return false;
   }
  }
```

And here is my php script to check:

```
<?php

require_once("../../includes/database.class.php");


if(isset($_POST['desusername'])){
    $username = $_POST['desusername'];

    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = $database->query($sql);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
?>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      <strong>Username already exists</strong>. Please choose a different one.
    </div>

<?php
 }else{
?>

    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <strong>Valid</strong>. You are good to go!
    </div>

<?php
 }
 exit();
}

?>
```

Now, in the developers console it shows its calling the function everytime i type:

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/members/authentication/checkusername.php".
```

But nothing is displaying in the relevant div (#name_status)..

Comment: do a console.log(response) within your success function and check the value

Comment: @KarthikGanesan ok, its coming up with this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: checkname is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup`

Comment: Perhaps add this to ajax call   `contentType: "application/json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see the response because you're using the wrong index on `checkusername.php`.
change below code

```
if(isset($_POST['desusername'])){
    $username = $_POST['desusername'];
```

to this

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
```

and you're good to go. :)

Make sure that

```
data: {
       key:value,
    },
```

You have to use `key` while fetching data from post request or get request.

Comment: The id and name of the input field is desusername, not username.

Comment: But you are sending data in ajax with `username` key

Comment: would key:value be this: username:desusername?

Comment: I get this error in console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: checkname is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup` now ive console.log(response)

Comment: is HTML and javascript in the same file?

Comment: yes, the html and javascript are, but the php is not

Comment: That error is showing your function is not defined.
So might be you've changed the function name in javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150848/discussion-between-milan-kyada-and-chris-marsland).